# Cannot Save Any WhatsApp Data Including Backup to Gmail/Google Account

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, gmail, xiaomi, google-drive, mi

Recently I bought a new phone (phone Y) - originally, I had been using WhatsApp as a dual app on someone else's phone (phone X), with a number whose SIM card was on a different cellphone (Phone Z). I was messaging people on phone X using the SIM card of phone Z, but when I saved contacts I saved it to a Gmail account instead. All was going well.

Then I wanted to switch over to using WhatsApp on Phone Y. As popularly advised, I went to the dual app on Phone X and backed up the data to Google Drive on my gmail account, but it never notified me of a finished backup. When I deleted the app on Phone X and installed it on Phone Y (which already knows and is linked the Gmail account), I keyed in the number of Phone Z (did not move the SIM because its not a microSIM, as required by Phone Y) and then it asked to give permission to access Google Drive for the backup. I gave it permission but then it said, no backup found.

True enough, I checked https://drive.google.com/drive/u/0/backups and it said there were no backups. I then got suspicious and checked my Google Contacts too - turns out it hadn't saved any of the contacts there either.

Which means the app was never importing any data to the google account, and still won't. Does anybody have any idea why this is happening??